# "TimeoutException: Cannot determine login status" - Selenium - Checking URL with loop

Tags: python, loops, selenium

Hi I am trying to make script that checks URL of current web page until the URL changes. And i have already done it and it works great but after some time i get
this error [Picture of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9cZc.png)

Any help would be appreciated: :-)

P.S. I am new to python so please be kind :D

*The script:*

```
import easygui
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER.EXE")
driver.get("URL OF SOME WEBSITE")
time.sleep(10)

b = "URL OF SOME WEBSITE"
a = driver.current_url

while a == b:
    a = driver.current_url
else:
     easygui.msgbox ("URL changed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a sleep in your while loop. If you don't, then you're sending commands to the browser as fast as your machine can handle (which isn't necessary) and that can cause issues.

```
while a == b:
    a = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(0.25)
else:
    easygui.msgbox ("URL changed")
```